# Redshift latency, i.e. discrepancy between "execution time" and "total runtime"

Tags: amazon-redshift, latency

I'm currently experimenting with Redshift and I've noticed that for a simple query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE column = 'value';
```

The execution time reported by Redshift is only 84ms, which is expected and pretty good with the table at ~33M rows. However, the total runtime, both observed on my local `psql` client as well as in Redshift's console UI is 5 seconds. I've tried the query on both a single node cluster and multi-node (2 nodes and 4 nodes) clusters.

In addition, when I try with more realistic, complicated queries, I can see similarly that the query execution itself is only ~500ms in a lot of cases, but the total runtime is ~7 seconds.

**What causes this discrepancy? Is there anyway to reduce this latency? Any internal table to dive deeper into the time distribution that covers the entire end-to-end runtime?**

I read about [Cold query performance improvements](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/06/amazon-redshift-now-delivers-better-cold-query-performance/) that Amazon recently introduced, but this latency seems to be there even on queries past the first cold one, as long as I alter the `value` in my where clause. However, the latency is somewhat inconsistent but definitely still go all the way up to 5 seconds.

-- Edited to give more details based on Bill Weiner's answer below --

- There is no difference between doing `SELECT COUNT(*)` vs `SELECT COUNT(column)` (where `column` is a dist key to avoid skew).
- There are absolutely zero other activities happening on the cluster because this is for exploration only. I'm the only one issuing queries and making connections to the DB, so there should be no queueing or locking delays.
- The data resides in the Redshift database, with a normal schema and common-sense dist key and sort key. I have not added explicit compression to any columns, so everything is just `AUTO` right now.

**Looks like compile time is the culprit!**

`STL_WLM_QUERY` shows that for query 12599, this is the `exec_start_time`/`exec_end_time`:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
userid                   | 100
xid                      | 14812605
task                     | 7289
query                    | 12599
service_class            | 100
slot_count               | 1
service_class_start_time | 2021-04-22 21:46:49.217
queue_start_time         | 2021-04-22 21:46:49.21707
queue_end_time           | 2021-04-22 21:46:49.21707
total_queue_time         | 0
exec_start_time          | 2021-04-22 21:46:49.217077
exec_end_time            | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.762903
total_exec_time          | 4545826
service_class_end_time   | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.762903
final_state              | Completed
est_peak_mem             | 2097152
query_priority           | Normal
service_class_name       | Default queue
```

And from `SVL_COMPILE`, we have:

```
 userid |   xid    |  pid  | query | segment | locus |         starttime          |          endtime           | compile
--------+----------+-------+-------+---------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------
    100 | 14812605 | 30442 | 12599 |       0 |     1 | 2021-04-22 21:46:49.218872 | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.744529 |       1
    100 | 14812605 | 30442 | 12599 |       2 |     2 | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.745711 | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.745728 |       0
    100 | 14812605 | 30442 | 12599 |       3 |     2 | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.761989 | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.762015 |       0
    100 | 14812605 | 30442 | 12599 |       1 |     1 | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.745476 | 2021-04-22 21:46:53.745503 |       0
(4 rows)
```

It shows that compile took from 21:46:49.218872 to 2021-04-22 21:46:53.744529, i.e. the overwhelming majority of the 4545ms total exec time.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot that could be taking up this time.  Looking a more of the query and queuing statistics will help track down what is happening.  Here are a few possibilities that I've seen be significant in the past:

1. Date return time.  Since your query is an open select and could be returning a meaningful amount of data and moving this over the network to the requesting computer takes time.
2. Queuing delays.  What else is happening on your cluster?  Does you query start right away or does it need to wait for a slot?
3. Locking delays.  What else is happening on your cluster?  Are data/tables changing? Is the data your query needs being committed elsewhere?
4. Compile time.  Is this the first time this query is run?
5. Is the table external? In S3 as an external table.  Or are you using the new rs3 instance type? All the source data is in S3.  (I'm guessing you are not on rs3 nodes but it doesn't hurt to ask)

A place to start is STL_WLM_QUERY to see where the query is spending this extra time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Bill! I edited the original question to add more details that answer the areas that you have pointed out to. Maybe compile time is the most likely culprit? If so, is there a way/table to definitively measure the compile time in the overall execution time?

Comment: It looks like compile but I always like to do reality checks.  Query compile plans are cached so a second run of the query with slight changes should not need to be recompiled - like changing the "value" in the where clause.  We need a change so the RS doesn't just return the cached result. See if you can detect the difference between cached and uncached query compilations.  In your svl_compile info above RS only recompiled the 0th segment and used cached code for the other 3.  I'd like to be sure I know what is happening since your compile time seems long for such a simple query.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help! I'm diving deeper with our actual queries to experiment with when queries/segments will need compile and when it reads from cache now. I guess the trick is now to make sure that we always have cached queries somehow, since it is pretty clear that triggering query compiling for any segment at all is pretty costly.